# Why does this recursion not work as expected in python

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables, permutation, local-variables

```
res = []
A = [1,2,3]

def permute(idx, path):
    
    if idx >= len(A):
        # base case
        print(path)
        res.append(path)
        return 
    
    for i in range(idx, len(A)):
        path[i],path[idx] = path[idx], path[i]
        permute(idx+1, path)
        path[i],path[idx] = path[idx], path[i]

permute(0,A)
print(res)
```

So I'm trying to build all the permutations of an array using recursion. Here in the base case if I try printing the `path` variable, I'm getting something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]
```

But I am appending the same path to the global `res` array and I'm getting this in the `res` list :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I found a turn-around by doing `res.append(list(path))` or a `res.append(path[:])`, it is working as expected. I'm having a hard time understanding how this is working. In the base case, I can see the changed `path` variable by printing it, does this not mean the same would be appended to the list?

Also, what is the best practice when I have to work with recursive functions and changing variables, is there any better way than not passing the entire variable every time?

Comment: Your entire program only contains two list objects.  One of them is `A` (also called `path`), and the other is `res`, which eventually contains six references to the other list.  Remember that Python doesn't COPY lists when passed as parameters.

Comment: @TimRoberts so when I do a `res.append(path)` it does not necessarily save the current state of the `path` list? I assume, I need to create another local variable to copy this state and then append it [thats what `path[:]` does]?

Comment: Right, it just adds another reference to the existing object.  Yes, `path[:]` makes a copy.